# Need to use multiple Go versions along with Makefiles

Tags: go, makefile

If I am working on multiple projects where different Go versions are required to build them, how would I elegantly set up my development environment to deal with this?

Each project has its own Makefile which at some point or the other would invoke Go commands. The issue is that some projects require different versions of Go, but the Makefiles simply use `go build`. My solution so far has been to simply add whichever Go version I needed to the `PATH` variable, e.g. project 1 requires go1.12.10, so I just run

```
export PATH=<path_to_go1.12.10_>/bin>:$PATH
```

And when I want to build project 2 which requires go1.13.6

```
export PATH=<path_to_go1.13.6>/bin:$PATH
```

This works, but is there a more elegant solution? Modifying the projects' build systems is not something I can do, at least not in the short term.

Comment: If you have docker installed I found it easy to try builds with different images.  DockerHub has images for all major versions back to Go 1.1.  Also there was a project somewhere on GitHub which allowed you to easily switch between Go compiler versions.  Also see https://dave.cheney.net/2014/04/20/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go build has no native way to set the version to build with, so you are stuck either setting the path like you are now, or executing explicitly using `/<path_to_go1.13.6>/bin/go.`

For the versions that you implied you are working with, there really *should* be no incompatibilities between them and the latest version of go. On of Go's tenants is to preserve backwards compatibility under basically all circumstances. You would most likely be better off using go's latest version, and, if something is preventing you from upgrading the compiler, fixing that instead.